# Trying to find the square root of an integer with linear search in Python without using the exponent operator

Tags: python, math

I wrote some code to find the square root of an integer without using the exponent operator and rounding down if the square root is between integers.

I can't figure out why my code breaks when the input integer is 1.

I used the floor division operator and the issue I face is that the code breaks when my iterator (i) is 1. However when I evaluate it piece by piece 1*1 >= 1 evaluates to True. 1 // 1 equals 1. So I don't understand why the code breaks and the return is None.

```
def mySqrt(x):
    if x == 0:
        return x

    for i in range(x):
        if i*i >= x:
            return x // i

print(mySqrt(4)) # Output 2
print(mySqrt(1)) # Output None
print(mySqrt(12)) # Output 3
```

Comment: remember to give [the `range()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) a quick read to make sure you remember what values that yields.

Answer (score 2):

In python, if you write range(x) it means that the range would be from 0 till x, where x is not included. Hence, in your code when you give x=1, the

```
for i in range(x):
        if i*i >= x:
            return x // i
```

the for loop only sets i=0 and then terminates. So for i=0, 0*0 = 0 and as 0<1 it never goes in the if condition and returns None.

The fix to your code would be as follows:

```
def mySqrt(x):
    if x == 0:
        return x

    for i in range(x+1): #changed the range to x+1
        if i*i >= x:
            return x // i

print(mySqrt(4)) # Output 2
print(mySqrt(1)) # Output 1
print(mySqrt(12)) # Output 3
```

Answer (score 1):

range(1) is actually equals to [0] (not list type actually). And since the 0*0 is not greater than or equal to 1 it just returns None.